# lightning-map Satellite default

Tags: lightning-web-components, google-map

I have LWC component lightning-map. How to make the default satellite view?

I did not find such an option in the documentation and I can't change it through the code because it's an iframe.

By default, the component is displayed as follows:
[image]

But I need it to be displayed by default like this
[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. As the documentation suggests, there is no exposed API for this attribute/toggle that we can use to change the default view mode.

What you could do is try writing your own implementation of the map component using Google Map's JavaScript SDK or something. That would require some more effort, but might give you what you want.

Using Google Map's SDK you can specify the `mapTypeId` attribute, as in:

```js
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: 'satellite'
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    mapOptions);
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes